What is the proper way to mark the removal version using @Deprecated?
I was asked to deprecate a couple classes to be deprecated and removed in a future release. Given the Javadocs there are 2 properties, the version it was deprecated in and whether or not it will be removed. So I ended up with a tag like this
@Deprecated(forRemoval = true)

I was then asked to add 2 things, first the version it will be removed. Now of course I could use comments or something along those lines but it doesn't seem like there is anything formal so are comments just the way to go or is there something I am missing? In this example the removal version is 4.5.0.
Also there is a since property, however, since we have multiple versions in parallel this doesn't seem intuitive. For example we might release a patch for version 4.3, 4.2 and 4.1 so technically on the 4.3 branch it would be marked deprecated since say 4.3.2 and on the 4.2 it would be since 4.2.5 and the 4.1 would be since 4.1.9. This means if you are on 4.3.1, 4.2.4, or 4.1.8 it won't be marked deprecated.
Am I relegated to comments to make this work or is there some way I can do all this with the annotations so it is recognized by the developer's IDE?

This problem is pretty well-known to be honest, and I can share some experience here.
First, there is no in-built way in java to specify the version of the software, in which the given API would be deleted. The parameter since is merely the version in which the API was marked for deprecation, quote from the doc:

The value of this element indicates the version in which the annotated program element was first deprecated.

I'm a community contributor to spring-data open source projects, and the API deprecation is a common thing. In case we deprecate some API, if we mark that forRemoval = true, it is simply removed in the next major release following the SemVer. I'm just letting you know how it is done by the hegemonies of the industry.  As for this statement:

Also there is a since property, however, since we have multiple versions in parallel this doesn't seem intuitive. For example we might release a patch for version 4.3, 4.2 and 4.1 so technically on the 4.3 branch it would be marked deprecated since say 4.3.2 and on the 4.2 it would be since 4.2.5 and the 4.1 would be since 4.1.9. This means if you are on 4.3.1, 4.2.4, or 4.1.8 it won't be marked deprecated.

This is totally fine. This is one of the many reasons why the previous major versions are still supported - because some API that is deleted in the major version 2 is present in the major version 1, and some client is not ready yet to migrate. That is why we're backporting patches into previous major release minor version, as you described, thats fine. This practice is adopted by JDK, Kotlin, Spring projects etc.

Am I relegated to comments to make this work or is there some way I can do all this with the annotations so it is recognized by the developer's IDE?

There is no compatible way to do this. You cannot know what IDE the person is using and what plugins or inspections are enabled.
What we can and should do is:

Add Java tag @deprecated and provide the meaningful explanation why the API is deprecated and when it will be removed.
Add Java tag @see to guide the user to the potential replacement for the API
And of course, do not forget to package the sources along with the .jar that contains the bytecode in order for the two suggestions above to work on developer's IDE, at least IntelliJ can download and parse the source jars.

Caring about users is a great thing, you're doing the right thing. But you cannot solve everything, so, do the best with what you've got.
P.S: Oracle official guide on deprecation of the API, from their perspective.

Thanks for trying to give a detailed answer but I am still a bit confused. So what version should I put as since? Would it just be the major 4? As for @see it is being removed with no replacement as it was bad practice so I don't think we need that. Also I think you misunderstand my IDE comment, I meant generally like the @Deprecated already works with IJ and that is basically all I have to worry about but I would assume if IJ can mark it others can as well so I was more referring to just the standard way most will recognize no a panacea

@JGleason since is the version from which you started the deprecation, let's consider your example. Let's say that current lib that you're developing has version 4.2.1. The decision was made to deprecate the API, so since is put as @since 4.2 in the javadoc. If there is no replacement, then this is what you put in the @deprecated, see as an example SecurityManager in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SecurityManager.html

As for the IDE comment - the @Deprecated annotation is the most recognizable as such. This is the most portable way to warn the user about deprecation.

I would say in may case the solution was to not mark it deprecated in the older versions as people would have to upgrade to get to the deprecation warning. Given that we are using OpenRewrite this seemed like a valid narrative so instead we moved the @Deprecated to just the latest branch and marked the since at that branch.
Not going to accept an answer though as this seems like a subjective thing.
